# is there a way to optimize cumprod in python?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm having a pandas data frame `df` and would like to perform the following calculation in a function. The line that takes by far the longest is a cumprod. I was wondering if there is a way to speed this up? Like in numpy they are different ways to achieve the same result, e.g. `np.inner` vs `np.einsum` and I was wondering if one can do something similar here.

```
import pandas as pd

In [122]: import numpy as np

In [123]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000, 1000))

In [124]: %time ((1+df).cumprod(axis=0)-1)
CPU times: user 5.22 s, sys: 884 ms, total: 6.1 s
Wall time: 6.12 s
```

Comment: Using `df.values` in place `df` should help it a bit.

Comment: @Divakar yes, I just wanted to highlight we can also assume that df is a numpy array.

Comment: Directly working with `np.cumprod` is about 10 % faster for me.

Comment: But your `df` is a dataframe.

Comment: np,multiply.accumulate might be a bit faster.

Comment: Considering `np.cumprod` is already c-compiled and faster than`np.multiply.accumulate`, I doubt there's much more optimization to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the computation in NumPy instead of Pandas.
For your input sizes this will be of the order of ~5%, not exciting but better than nothing. For smaller inputs, the gains are much more significant.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randn(100000, 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

x = ((1 + df).cumprod(axis=0) - 1)
y = np.cumprod(1 + arr, axis=0) - 1

print(np.allclose(x, y))
```

Given that this is the same result, the timings are:

```
arr = np.random.randn(100000, 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

%timeit ((1 + df).cumprod(axis=0) - 1)
# 3.64 s ± 76.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.cumprod(1 + arr, axis=0) - 1
# 3.42 s ± 19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

showing the aforementioned speed gains for your inputs.

For smaller inputs, the difference is larger, e.g.:

```
arr = np.random.randn(1000, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

%timeit ((1 + df).cumprod(axis=0) - 1)
# 469 µs ± 4.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit np.cumprod(1 + arr, axis=0) - 1
# 36.6 µs ± 427 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

showing that in this case doing the computation in NumPy is ~13x faster than in Pandas.

---

## EDIT:

As suggested by @hpaulj, `np.multiply.accumulate()` can get slightly faster.

```
# for shape = (100000, 1000)
%timeit np.multiply.accumulate(1 + arr, axis=0) - 1
# 3.38 s ± 79.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and, for smaller inputs:

```
# for shape = (1000, 10)
%timeit np.multiply.accumulate(1 + arr, axis=0) - 1
# 35.8 µs ± 423 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

But, as always, these kind of micro-benchmarks should be taken with a grain of salt, especially when such small differences are observed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use other modules to speed up your calculations, I can recommend `numba`. Numba compiles python code to LLVM and is specifically aiming to speed up numeric calculations using `numpy`.

Since `numba` does not yet support using `kwargs` like `axis=0` with `np.cumprod`, your code will look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def nb_cumprod(arr):
    y = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
        y[:, i] = np.cumprod(1 + arr[:, i]) - 1
    return y

arr = np.random.randn(100000, 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

x = ((1 + df).cumprod(axis=0) - 1)
y = np.cumprod(1 + arr, axis=0) - 1
z = nb_cumprod(arr)

print(np.allclose(x, z))
```

And some timings show that numba is about 4 times faster than using cumprod on a DataFrame and about 3.7 times faster than using numpy:

```
%timeit ((1 + df).cumprod(axis=0) - 1)
# 6.83 s ± 482 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.cumprod(1 + arr, axis=0) - 1
# 6.38 s ± 509 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit nb_cumprod(arr)
# 1.71 s ± 158 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

You can use additional options like `fastmath=True` to increase the performance even further, but this will yield *slightly* different results.